# Get AJAX data from server before document ready (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, document-ready

I want take some data from server and write it to global array in JavaScript. Then in document ready I want to use this array to create some new elements (options). I should have global array with this data, because after first load client can modify user interface using this data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    UseAjaxQueryForFillGlobalArray();
    MakingInterfaceUsingGlobalArray();       
});
```

But I have strange behavior, when I debug page, I can see that method *MakingInterfaceUsingGlobalArray* working first, and just after I get data via AJAX with method *UseAjaxQueryForFillGlobalArray* and I don't have new interface(html options) with loaded data.

If I do like this:

```
UseAjaxQueryForFillGlobalArray();
$(document).ready(function () {     
    MakingInterfaceUsingGlobalArray();       
});
```

Then in Firefox working fine, but in another web-browsers incorrect in first load (for example go to this page by link). But if I refreshing by F5, I have correct user interface which loaded via AJAX to global JS array.

How to fix it? Maybe I using totally incorrect way?

**Added after comments**:

This is my ajax function:

```
function UseAjaxQueryForFillGlobalArray(){
    var curUserId = '<%= Master.CurrentUserDetails.Id %>';
    var curLocale = '<%= Master.CurrentLocale %>';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/segment.aspx/GetArrayForCF",
        data: '{"userId":"' + curUserId + '","curLocale":"' + curLocale + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            //here is I doing parse my string from server and fill arrays.     
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You forgot to actually add the link to your example.

Comment: Show us your jQuery ajax code. There's a property (`async`) which may be what you need.

Comment: On a sidenote: for initial page rendering I would advise you to transfer all the data needed in a single request, instead of loading a basically "blank" page and then loading data via ajax into it.

Comment: I have added ajax function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you don't know exactly when the first function returns, since it'a asynchronous. So you should use the array in the callback only

```
function UseAjaxQueryForFillGlobalArray() {
    // make the call
    $.post(url, data, function() {
        // let's be sure that the dom is ready
        $(document).ready(function () {    
            // use the array
            MakingInterfaceUsingGlobalArray();      
        }
    }
}();// invoke the function
```

Comment: Thank you! But instead of $.post I used $.ajax, because I had 500 error from server.

Answer (score 4):

It's like reviving this post from the dead, but I had the same problem today, jQuery version greater than 1.6 has this ability:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/

And I've used it like this:

```
$.holdReady(true);
var remoteJSONContent = null;
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/remote.json", function(data) {
    remoteJSONContent = data;
    $.holdReady(false);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(remoteJSONContent);
});
```

Without using `holdReady`, I was getting null, after, I got the content.

For anyone still searching the answer for this.