# Web page does not wait for my codes run completely

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cookies

I need to run these commands:

1. Get cookie from browser by JS Cookie plugin in **mypage.php**
2. Check its value by Ajax and my PHP codes in **myapi.php**
3. Assign some SESSIONs in **myapi.php**
4. And now use those SESSION values in *many php vars*
   in bottom of page in **mypage.php**

but those *many php vars* defined by default values and need to ONE MORE TIME REFRESH. Can I use cookie by PHP directly? And how?

This is my code in mypage.php:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
            if (typeof Cookies.get( 'isuser' ) != 'undefined') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: apiaddress,
                    data: {action: 'verify_user', verifycode: Cookies.get( 'isuser' )},
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    async: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result['status'] == 'OK') {
                            //some code like welcome
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This is my code in myapi.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'verify_user') {
        $usercookie = !empty($_POST['verifycode']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['verifycode']) : '';
        $usercookie_a = explode('*', $usercookie);
        $username = $usercookie_a[0];
        $uservcode = $usercookie_a[1];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND vcode = '$uservcode'";
        if ($result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $counts = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($counts == 1) {
                $output = [];
                $output['status'] = 'OK';
                $output['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['isuseru'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['isuserp'] = $row['password'];
                echo json_encode($output);
                unset($_POST);
            }
        } else {
            echo 'MySQL Connection Error: ' . mysqli_error($db);
        }
    }
```

And now I want use $_SESSION['isuseru'] and others in mypage.php but those are not in hand in first time and need to refresh.

Comment: Add your code sample

Comment: @RahulReghunath My codes was added.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may go with [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) by enclosing the ajax call in mypage.php so that you can get hold of the those session values.

or use timeout in the jquery ajax as specified in the 
[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: No this is not problem. I want to run Ajax faster before reach to bottom of that page because I need those SESSION Vars. I need to wait to run Ajax completely and then other codes in bottom of that page run. Most of them in PHP and I check usleep(5000); after that Ajax, but not work.

Comment: If so then you can go with the callback in the ajax success if applicable, like mentioned in the below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481863/get-ajax-data-from-server-before-document-ready-jquery

Comment: That is good recommendation. But my other codes in PHP and I do not know how to run it before "document is ready". I try to convert some of them to JS and use your suggestion.